# Alternatives for "lsof" command?

Tags: process, open-files, administration, lsof

In many cases `lsof` is not installed on the machines that I have to work with, but the "function" of `lsof` would be needed very much (for example on AIX). :\

Are there any `lsof` like applications in the non-Windows world?

For example, I need to know which processes use the `/home/username` directory?

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? What systems apart from AIX (which is definitely supported by lsof) do you have in mind? Or is there only one specific type of use of lsof you have in mind? Generally: why *not* lsof?

Comment: I'm using Linux 2.6.18-92.el5 GNU, and I don't have lsof, nor do I have the capability to use lsof :(

Comment: Related question: [how to check open file without lsof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796298/how-to-check-open-file-without-lsof)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I know of [`fuser`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29), see if it's available on your system.

Comment: what do i have to give fuser as parameter to list all open files on a system? :O ty!

Comment: The command `sudo fuser -vm / 2>&1 | awk '$3 ~ /f|F/' | less` can show all processes having open files on the filesystem mounted on `/`. See man page for specific help.

Comment: TY! it gives output like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2z19g6Rk - i googled for it, but i can't find any way to output ex.: "gnome-screensaver", not "gnome-screensav" - so how can i output it with wide command names? :O

Comment: it gives the same output for: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Fe3EJvUv

Comment: Something like this: `sudo fuser -vm / 2>&1 | awk '$3 ~ /f|F/' | while read user pid flags rest; do printf '%10s %10s %10s %s\n' $user $pid $flags "$(</proc/$pid/cmdline)"; done | less`

Comment: I would say `ps uww --pid $(fuser -vm / 2>&1 | awk '$3 ~ /[fF]/ { print $2 }') | less`. With a bit tweaking, you can get the file in front of it.

Comment: `fuser` is also unavailable for me. Got some results with `netstat -p -x`

Answer (score 17):

The [Unix Rosetta Stone](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) is a good resource for this kind of questions. It mentions a few alternatives for [lsof](http://people.freebsd.org/~abe/) (see below). Do note however that lsof is the de facto standard application for what it does.

If all you want is to find the process ID(s) that have a particular file open, then you can use [`fuser`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/fuser.html) on any POSIX-compliant system.

On operating systems with a `/proc` directory, you can query the files open by a process (the reverse from `lsof`'s most common mode of operation) through information in `/proc`. Some operating systems have commands for that:

- AIX: [`procfiles`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/procfiles.htm) is shipped with the system (since AIX 5.2). See also [AIX 5.2 performance tools update](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/articles/AIX5.2PerfTools.html#pfs) and [Usage and examples of lsof, pfiles, procfiles commands](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21306599).
- [Solaris](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/legacy-solaris-192993.html): `pfiles` (existing [since 2.5](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19641-01/802-1930-01/802-1930-01.pdf)).

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to run Solaris, an alternative to `lsof`, which isn't installed by default and might choke on ZFS, is `pfiles`.

eg:

`pfiles /proc/*`

Answer (score 4):

My version, with only a little less running of utilities:

```
for proc_pid in $(find /proc -maxdepth 1 -name "[0-9]*"); do \
    ls -l ${proc_pid}/fd 2>/dev/null \
    | grep -q "$search_term" \
    && echo "${proc_pid#/proc/}"; \
done
```

Admittedly, it may not handle all corner cases, but is working in my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It'll give the all the file descriptor mappings except those which:

- you don't have permission to view, or
- are for files which contain the string "Permission denied"

```bsh
( find /proc -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  | grep -E [0-9]+ | xargs -n 1 -I% find %/fd \
  | xargs ls -l \
  | grep -v "Permission denied" ) 2>/dev/null \
| cut -d' ' -f12- | less
```

If you already know you only care about the mappings for certain programs, you could instead use something more along the lines of:

```
exec=sshd
pgrep "$exec" | xargs -n 1 ps -p
pgrep "$exec" | xargs -n 1 -I% find /proc/%/fd | xargs ls -l | cut -d' ' -f12- | less
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `lsof` is installed in `/usr/sbin`

If `/usr/sbin` is not part of your `$PATH`, you could miss the command even installed.

Check it with

```
whereis lsof
lsof: /usr/sbin/lsof /usr/share/man/man8/lsof.8.gz
```

Comment: The OP said that lsof was not installed and asked for alternatives...

Comment: Great thanks. Found it. Earlier, I had searching in many paths including /usr/bin/ and never found. Your post definitely helped. And introduced to a new path!